# Error after opening an excel file created in C#

Tags: c#, excel

Good morning,

I created a simple file using this code ;

```
    public static void createExcelFile(string path, Projet projet)
    {
        string totalPath = path + @"/" + projet.Nom_du_projet + ".xls";

        File.Create(totalPath).Close();

        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet(projet.Nom_du_projet);
        workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
        worksheet.Cells[0, 0] = new Cell(projet.Nom_du_projet);
        workbook.Save(totalPath);
        Process.Start(path);
    }
```

I don't know why, but when the file opens, I get this message from excel :

.........

In English, it says:

> "Sorry, we found a problem in the contents of , but
>   we can try to recover as much of the content as possible. If the
>   source of this workbook is reliable, click yes"

When I press yes, I fall on my binder exactly as I asked, without error.

Do you have a solution?

Thank you

Comment: Add your File.Close() at the end, not right after you create the workbook

Comment: I would remove the `File.Create` line altogether and just use `Workbook.SaveAs`.  There is no need to create the file first.